# XML serializing arrays with type="array" in .NET

Tags: .net, arrays, xml-serialization, activeresource

I'm attempting to serialize a class to XML, but I have some strict requirements on the output (because I want Rails' ActiveResource to consume it).  One of those requirements is specifically for arrays.  Here's two examples:

```
class Person { public string FirstName { get; set; } }

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add( new Person {...} );
people.Add( new Person {...} );
```

If I serialize the people list, I need this output:

```
<People type="array">
  <Person>
    <FirstName>blah</FirstName>
  </Person>
  <Person>...</Person>
</People>
```

Another example is like this:

```
class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
  public string Line1 { get; set; }
}
```

If a serialize a person, I need this output:

```
<Person>
  <FirstName>blah</FirstName>
  <Addresses type="array">
    <Address>...</Address>
  </Addresses>
</Person>
```

Is there anyway to trick the XmlSerializer into producing this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also take a look at [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(VS.71).aspx).

Something like this may work for you

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="People")]
public class PeopleType
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Person")]
    public List<Person> people  = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person { FirstName = "Bob" },
        new Person { FirstName = "Sally" }
    };

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type = "array";
}

PeopleType p = new PeopleType();
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PeopleType));
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("out.xml", false))
    xs.Serialize(sw, p, ns);
```

Comment: This works great.  I just want to point out that it does NOT work with JSON serialization however.  You'll get {"people":[...]} when what you want is just [...].  That it said, it solves the xml issue perfectly.