# Serialize boolean array column in XSD file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

My dataset is defined in an XSD file and i am not generating it from the code. Only 1 table is using a data column with type System.Boolean[] and only this column is giving exception when i use table.WriteXmlSchema().

> Boolean[] is a complex type.Cannot Serialize value of a complex type
>   as Attribute.

I am using the code from the following website.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2010/04/02/dataset-does-not-validate-xml-schema-xsd.aspx

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\abc.xsd");
String test = currentDataset.GetXmlSchema(); //exception
currentDataset.WriteXmlSchema(writer);
```

My goal: To validate my XML against a Schema (before i load the XML itself). Validating the schema will give me exact error details.

My approach: Generate XSD -> Use the XSD to validate the XML -> If everything fine then go ahead -> If problem then show the proper error to the user so that he can fix the XML manually.

Any help will be greatly appreacited.

Comment: Are you using `Boolean` or `bool` as the type? If you're using `Boolean` try switching `bool`. I'd have to see how you setup your datasource and xsd to be more helpful. Although `boolean` [should](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx) be serializable.

Comment: i am using bool[] (boolean array) and boolean array is causing the problem.

Comment: I believe the answer below looks to be the most right. You can't really have a complex type that doesn't have an XmlElement attribute attached. Try List maybe? refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211859/xml-serializing-arrays-with-type-array-in-net

Answer (score 1):

As per XSD, an attribute can only be a simple content. Since Boolean[] is a complex type, it can't be serialized as an attribute. Try using [XmlElement] instead of [XmlAttribute] on your bool[] property.

Comment: I actually checked in the code. The column was already XMLElement. :(. But i will visit the office on thursday and will recheck again and will let you know.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response. The Boolean[] is set as an XMLElement. I tried alot but i have not found the answer yet.